# Draw networkx graph from lists

Tags: python, plotly, networkx

I have the following lists:

```
l1=["a", "a", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
l2=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
l3=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
l4=[12, 14, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88]
l=[l1, l2, l3, l4]
```

And I want to create and draw a networkx graph from these lists with a given number of nodes, such that there is an edge between the elements of the same list.
In the example above, assuming the number of nodes is 20, the graph nodes should be:

```
(('a'), ('1'), ('A'), (12), ('c'), ('3'), ('C'), (22), ('d'), ('4'), ('D'), (33))
```

Without taking into account `('a'), ('2'), ('B'), (14)` because there is already a node 'a'. Therefore, the other lists' elements in the same position must not be considered.
The graph edges should be:

```
(['a', 'c'], ['c', 'd'], ['d', 'e'], ['e', 'f'],
 ['1', '3'], ['3', '4'], ['4', '5'], ['5', '6'], 
 ['A', 'C'], ['C', 'D'], ['D', 'E'], ['E', 'F'],
 [12, 22], [22, 33], [33, 44], [44, 55])
```

These edges must be vertical. I wrote the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
for j in range(int(20/len(l))): 
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if G.number_of_nodes()<20:
            G.add_node(l[i][j], pos=(i*2, j))
            if j>0 and l[i][j]!=l[i][j-1]:
                G.add_edge(l[i][j], l[i][j-1])
```

But it seems it doesn't work properly. The nodes and edges' lists I got are:

```
NodeView(('a', '1', 'A', 12, '2', 'B', 14, 'c', '3', 'C', 22, 'd', '4', 'D', 33, 'e', '5', 'E', 44))

EdgeView([('a', 'c'), ('1', '2'), ('A', 'B'), (12, 14), ('2', '3'), ('B', 'C'), (14, 22), ('c', 'd'), ('3', '4'), ('C', 'D'), (22, 33), ('d', 'e'), ('4', '5'), ('D', 'E'), (33, 44)])
```

The edges list is not like I described above. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't it be `l[j][i]` instead of `l[i][j]`? `j` goes from `0` to `3` and `i` goes from `0` to `8`. `l[3][8]` is valid but `l[8][3]` is out of bounds. _"But it seems it doesn't work properly."_ What does it mean? What is the problem with this code?

Comment: @ThomasSablik, I edited the code ```range(20/len(l))``` instead of ```range(len(l))``` so as de define the number of levels (which is 4 in this example). But for your note, it should be  ```l[j][i]``` and not ```l[i][j]``` in order to iterate the lists' element of the same 'level' simultaneously'. I added the result I got to show the list of edges.

Comment: Please provide an actual working [mcve]. There are multiple errors in your code. It's not possible that this code produces any output other than error messages.

Comment: Where do `(('a'), ('1'), ('A'), (12), ('b'), ('2'), ('B'), (14), ('c'), ('3'), ('C'), (22))` and `(('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('1', '2'), ('2', '3'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), (12, 14), (14, 22))` come from?

Comment: `j` goes from `0` to `4` and `i` goes from `0` to `3`. That's 5*4=20 nodes. `j` skips `0` for the edges. That's 4*4=16 edges. Why do you expect a different result? _"The edges list is not like I described above."_ The edges list is exactly like you described. It connects all nodes in each list.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, I changed the list l1 to give an example. The second element of l1 is 'a' which is already a node because its predecessor is 'a'. In this case, the elements of the second position in the other lists should not considered

Comment: Do you have an algorithm for this or is this an algorithm question? Are you able to solve the problem with pen and paper? You could add `if l[0][j] in G.nodes: continue` between both `for` loops.

Comment: Here is an example https://wandbox.org/permlink/UZSpdsHHtFFr3VbT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx

def create_graph(l):
    G=nx.Graph()
    for j in range(len(l[0])):
        if l[0][j] in G.nodes:
            continue
        for i in range(len(l)):
            if G.number_of_nodes() >= 20:
                return G
            G.add_node(l[i][j], pos=(i*2, j))
            if j>0 and l[i][j]!=l[i][j-1]:
                G.add_edge(l[i][j], l[i][j-1])

l1=["a", "a", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
l2=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
l3=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
l4=[12, 14, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88]
l=[l1, l2, l3, l4]

G = create_graph(l)
print(G.nodes)
print(G.edges)
```